# Joining scaffolds to get full genome?

Tags: ngs

I am using Ray to assemble a about 7.2 kb picornavirus genome. I am using k-mer of 55. Following is the exact code that I used.

```
mpiexec -n 1 Ray -k 55 -s 2-CA-SVA-2_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq_q30_trim_LR_15.fasta  -o rayd55tr
```

This worked quite well as I got a `scaffolds.fasta` file with two scaffolds one with 5730 bp and another with 1548 bp.

Now, I am confused how I can join those scaffolds to get one linear genome. I joined them manually and blasted just to check and I got something like below :[image: Blast of the manually joined contigs].

Is there any tool to join these two contigs together to have one complete linear genome? I have reference genome too if needed.

Comment: What did you blast against? Your image just shows a few identical sequences, but we can't interpret any blast results without knowing what was blasted against what. Also, if you have a reference genome, why didn't you use that to assemble the contigs?

Comment: Are there any good tools available for reference based contigs joining ?

Comment: It is quite important to know what kind of sequencing data you have used for people to provide accurate tips.

Answer (score 2):

[Ragout](http://fenderglass.github.io/Ragout/) worked well for me. It is a reference-based scaffolder.

```
ragout.py --outdir output/ input/ragout.rcp > message.txt 2> error.txt --threads 8 --overwrite
```

The ragout.rcp file contains a 'recipe' with the reference sequence and the contigs in FASTA format.:

```
.references = ensembl
.target = assembly

ensembl.fasta = ref.fa
assembly.fasta = contigs.fa
```

In my case, it reduced the number of contigs 10-fold and increased the N50 10-fold. It added N's between the contigs.

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer. How/when does it work well ? How will it help the OP in their case?

Comment: I have added my code and what Ragout did for me. What does 'OP' mean?

Comment: Great [edit]! OP comes from Original Poster to refer the one that asked the question. I hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you might consider reference-based scaffolding, as per [charlesdarwin's answer](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/2944/196). I would argue that in most cases this will only provide limited information, as this will only really provide you with the order of the contigs *as it is in your reference*, as opposed to how it is in your sampled organism. In that sense it really only provides pseudo-scaffolding that makes your assembly look artificially good.

In all cases you will have to check wether your raw data supports your scaffolding solution.

Example: you will never be able to call structural variants across contig boundaries if you use reference based scaffolding.

I would suggest you try different k-mer sized for your assembly algorithm, and look into dedicated scaffolding tools. Without knowing your type of sequencing data it is hard to suggest anything specific.